# Avert value duplicating

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose we have table A:

```
Customer_number  |  Region_id
-----------------------------
123              |  1
132              |  1
256              |  2
213              |  3
```

And I want to insert some customers into table A. But each time I want to insert new customer into A, I must first delete from A rows with Region_id that i'm intending to insert into A.
For example I want to insert following rows into A:

```
Customer_number  |  Region_id
-----------------------------
564              |  1
846              |  5
```

But I want oracle somehow to give me a hint that there is already Region_id=1 in A, so I must first delete it from A and then only insert my new rows. And the result should look like this:

```
Customer_number  |  Region_id
-----------------------------
256              |  2
213              |  3
564              |  1
846              |  5
```

Please, propose any approach for restriction of inserting rows that intersect by Region_id like in example above.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606 and constraints (unique keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating trigger on the table should work as you wish.

```
create or replace trigger trg_a_region_id before insert on A for each row
begin
    delete a where Region_id=:new.Region_id;
    if sql%rowcount>0
    then
      dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount ||' rows deleted');
    end if;
 end;
```

instead of delete statement you can raise user defined exception (saying that manual deletion is required, or whatever you want).

however, use triggers carefully, from design point of view they are not always a good solution. i would rather put business logic in stored procedures.